# Jquery clone method to clone mutliple (more than one) div's (not a single div multiple times) inside a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need a method to clone say 4 div's with id's like d_1, d_2, d_3, d_4
including the contents inside each div all at once and then detach all divs, and then I need to find copy of d_1 and its contents from the clone and append it again to the page.

something like:

```
        var cloned=$('[id^="d_"]').clone();

        $('[id^="d_"]').detach();
```

and then find div with `id =d_1` from clone and append it to body.

Is it possible?

Comment: Why would you clone and then detach the originals? Why not just detach and/or append the originals themselves?

Comment: @Blazemonger  I cannot just remove them, since actually i might need all those divs in the same page ,but its like when i click a button/tab i need one of the div while others detached (and there is form inside each of the div to be submitted) and upon clicking another button/tab  i need a different div while others detached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Document Fragment.

```
var $documentFragment = $(document.createDocumentFragment());
$('[id^="d_"]').each(function(){
   $documentFragment.append($(this).clone().addClass("_cloned"));
});

$documentFragment.clone().appendTo(document.body);
```

If you want looking for an element into the fragment, you can do this:

```
$(document.body).find("#d_1._cloned"). ... ;
```

If you want to remove all the element and then append only the first copied into fragment:

```
$("._cloned", document.body).remove();
$documentFragment.find("#d_1").clone().appendTo(document.body);
```

Comment: Thanks, let me check it

Comment: i do not want to remove the elements all at once, i need them just detached for the moment, but i will need them back between button/tab clicks , like i need to switch back and forth between the divs , for submitting forms inside each of the divs separately.
Forms should remain independent and without conflicting

Comment: With fragment you can. Once you have created it, you can use it as you want. Append, remove or clone it how many times you need..

Comment: $documentFragment.remove();
$documentFragment.find("#d_1").appendTo(document.body);

with $documentFragment.remove(); , its not removing all other div's from page

Comment: Yep, there was a bit problem. When you use fragment you have to append to body a clone of the fragment. Because when fragment is appended it become empty. In order to remove all elements add a class to all cloned elements and then remove all elements having that class. If you find this too hard, you an array of cloned elements and loop it every time you want to remove or append it.

Answer (score 1):

You can `appendTo()` an element to detach and move an element elsewhere.

```
var els = $('[id^="d_"]')

els.detach();

els.each(function() {
  if (this.id.indexOf('d_1') !== -1) {
    $(this).appendTo(document.body);
  }
});

// do something else with els later, too.
```

Comment: shouldn't i fetch the id to be appended by looping through cloned via array etc ?

Comment: but they are detached, need to fetch them from clone,                                 
ALso I cannot just remove them, since actually i might need all those divs in the same page ,but its like when i click a button/tab i need one of the div while others detached (and there is form inside each of the div to be submitted) and upon clicking another button/tab i need a different div while others detached.                        Thanks

Comment: Updated again... I don't believe clone is needed unless I'm completely misunderstanding (quite possible).

Comment: i do not want to remove the elements all at once, i need then just detached, but i will need them back between button/tab clicks , like i need to switch back and forth between the divs , for submitting forms inside each of the divs separately